# No Such Column BillingAddress on entity Account

Tags: rest-api

I am getting this error for other fields across other objects too!

I am using simple_salesforce python package which is basically a rest api client. This used to work earlier but suddenly stopped working from last week without any change in the organisation setup. Also seems that the field security settings allow everyone to edit this field. So I wonder what changed in last few days that this is breaking.

Answer (score 4):

BillingAddress is a Compound Field and cannot be accessed traditionally.

> Compound fields group together multiple elements of primitive data types, such as numbers or strings, to represent complex data types, such as a location or an address. Compound fields are an abstraction that can simplify application code that handles the values, leading to more concise, understandable code.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/compound_fields.htm

Complete documentation on how to use **address** compound fields see below:

> Using compound fields can simplify code that works with addresses, especially for SOQL queries. SOQL SELECT clauses can reference addresses directly, instead of all of the individual component fields.

```
SELECT Name, BillingAddress
FROM Account
```

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/compound_fields_address.htm

**API Must be set to 30.0 or above**

It is hard to tell exactly what your issue is though since you did not show the code throwing the error but the above should get you the info you need.

**Note** You cannot do `BillingAddress.BillingStreet`, you would need to do `BilingAddress.getStreet()` depending on what you are trying to do